# protractor test before initial promises resolve

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I want to test the state of the controller after initialization completes, but before promises resolve.

I have a button which is disabled (by class) until loading completes:

```
<button ng-class="{disabled: isLoading}">Show</button>
```

When the controller is initialized, an ajax call is made and when it resolves, the isLoading is set to false:

```
$scope.isLoading = true;
$http.get('/list')
  .then(function(response) {
     $scope.list = response.data;
     $scope.isLoading = false;
  });
```

When I test the button using protractor, there is no disabled class.

```
it('should enable the button after load completes', function() {
    element(by.buttonText('Show')).getAttribute('class')
        .then(function(buttonClasses) {
            expect(buttonClasses).toContain('disabled');
        });
});
```

I modified the button to have another class, just to see I'm not going bonkers:

```
<button ng-class="{disabled: isLoading, enabled: !isLoading}">Show</button>
```

and the test:

```
it('should show the select tables list after clicking the Change button', function() {
    element(by.buttonText('Show')).getAttribute('class')
        .then(function(buttonClasses) {
            expect(buttonClasses).toContain('enabled');
        });
});
```

Now the test passes.

I'm guessing that `waitForAngular` is part of the controller initialization process. How do I test the state of the button **Before** the promise resolves?

Comment: Not necessarily an answer to the question, but consider using [`ngDisabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled) rather than `ngClass` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` before finding the element/class to not wait for promises in the app to resolve

```
it('should show the select tables list after clicking the Change button', function() {
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = true; 
  expect(element(by.buttonText('Show')).getAttribute('class')).toContain('disabled');
  browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
});
```

Note you rarely need to use `.then` callbacks for `expect`, since `expect` handles unwraping of the promises.